# binning files into approximately equal sized directories

Tags: python, language-agnostic

Given a sorted list of filenames of the form

```
{artist}-{title}.mp3
```

I want to distribute the files into 255 bins (subdirectories) so that each bin contains approximately equal numbers of files, with the restriction that artists are "atomic" i.e. that no artist should have tracks distributed over more than one directory.  The result should remain sorted aswell (i.e. ignoring the binning, we still have the same ordering of the list).

What I've already tried: I partition the list into exactly 255 parts by this method:

```
def partition(lst, n):
    q, r = divmod(len(lst), n)
    indices = [q * i + min(i, r) for i in range(n + 1)]
    result = [lst[indices[i]:indices[i + 1]] for i in range(n)]
    assert sum(len(x) for x in result) == len(lst)
    assert len(set(len(x) for x in result)) <= 2
    return result
```

And then I go through and enforce the restriction that artists are atomic by moving them into the previous bin if they already have another track there.  This method is sub-optimal and broken, because I'm left with a lot of empty bins (due to having, in some cases, many tracks by same artist)

Comment: I don't have time to implement this so here is some pseudo-code: get an artist name from the list, move all the files that belong to that artist to a separate list (call it `a`) and remove them from the initial list. get the directory the has the least files in it (write a function for this), add the files in list `a` to the directory you got earlier. Repeat this until there are no more files in your initial list.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that the sorting should be preserved, which means your suggestion doesn't work.  I'll edit it into the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hacking away at it for an hour, here's a better solution I came up with.  It works by creating a `dict` of artist to tracks, and then whittling it down to 255 keys by greedily pairing up adjacent entries when they are small.

I'm sure it's still not optimal, but it's workable and I'll reproduce it here in case anyone has a similar problem to solve:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict()
# build an OrderedDict of artist to track(s)
for fn in files:
    artist, title = fn.split('-')
    if (artist,) not in d:
        d[artist,] = []
    d[artist,].append(fn)

def window(seq, n=2):
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(itertools.islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result

while len(d) > 255:
    # find the pair of adjacent keys with minimal number of files contained
    k1, k2 = min(window(d), key=lambda x: len(d[x[0]] + d[x[1]]))
    # join them into the first key and nuke the latter
    d[k1] += d.pop(k2)
```

Comment: This is roughly what I was thinking of.  Absent any foreknowledge of alphabetical distribution of sample, I think it's a winner.  Of course, depending on sample size, doing 2 passes through your data might yield better results.