# Most efficient way to combine list of lists to get groups of items <= but as close as possible to length X

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

Say I have a list of lists like:

```
 [ [ a1, a2, a3, a4, a5], [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8], [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6], [d1, d2, d3, d4] ]
```

What's the easiest way to compare all the list item lengths and combine them into a list of lists with lengths as close as possible to, but less than or equal to, x?

So with the above example, and x=12:

```
[ [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6], [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, d1, d2, d3, d4] ]
```

The ordering of the individual groups (e.g a, b, c...) in the output isn't important, but individual groups cannot be broken up.

I know I could, for instance, take the length of the first group, then get the length of each subsequent group in order and if their sum = x then pop those lists and append their items to the returned list, and if not then work through each group again checking if the sum of their lengths=x-1 and if so pop and append, and on with sum of lengths=x-2 etc until the input list is empty.

Which will work fine for small groups like the example given, but what about when the len of the input list gets very large?  Is there a more efficient method / algorithm?

Comment: I would start out building a dict of array lengths. Like {4:[3], 5:[0], 6:[2], 8:[1]...} where each length is key to a list of indices in the original list of lists. I would then go through allocating elements that add up to nearest to the max. Then repeat incrementally to try to 'fill up' the groups.

Comment: This seems similar to the Knapsack problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: See [binning files into approximately equal sized directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16017197/674039)

Comment: This is known as the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). The [greedy solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#First-fit_algorithm) works well enough for most applications.

Comment: How do you pick whether to make lists of length (12, 12, 1) vs (12, 6, 7) vs (12, 10, 3) vs ... ?

Comment: @PMende that isn't important for my case, it is only the minimal number of total lists/bins that is important.  I'm actually using this to optimise the ordering of samples being run through an analytical lab to reduce the number of QC samples that need to be run (that are run between a max of X samples) to the absolute minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bin packing problem.

My [greedy algorithm with swapping and pre-sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626520/fitting-n-variable-height-images-into-3-similar-length-column-layout/5689594#5689594) should work, but you would need to adapt sub-list length to picture height, and compute an initial bin-count from your x and the total length of items.

Comment: I think that Wiki was exactly what I was looking for!  The Modified First Fit Decreasing should work for what I need, although I note they reference a paper containing a mathematically optimum solution:  Benkő A., Dósa G., Tuza Z. (2010) Bin Packing/Covering with Delivery, Solved with the Evolution of Algorithms, Proceedings 2010 IEEE 5th International Conference on Bio-Inspired Computing: Theories and Applications, BIC-TA 2010, art. no. 5645312, Pages 298-302.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not necessarily find the length-optimal solution as it considers joining only two lists but it runs in O(n).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import random

def foo(xs, n):
    bins = {}
    mid = (n+1)//2

    # bin list positions by length
    for i, x in enumerate(xs):
        bucket = len(x)
        if bucket > n:
            raise RuntimeError("invalid input")

        bins.setdefault(bucket, []).append(i)

    # take out ones that are the desired length already
    out = [xs[x] for x in bins[n]] if n in bins else []
    bins.pop(n, None)

    # find complements for the upper half of buckets
    for i in list(bins.keys()):
        if i < mid:
            continue

        candidates = sorted([x for x in list(bins.keys()) if x <= n-i], reverse=True)

        while i in bins and bins[i]:
            x = bins[i].pop()

            for j in list(candidates):
                if j not in bins or not bins[j]:
                    candidates = candidates[1:]
                    continue

                y = bins[j].pop()
                if not bins[j]:
                    del bins[j]

                out.append(xs[x] + xs[y])
                break
            else:
                # complement not found
                out.append(xs[x])


    # add lists with no complements from the lower half
    out += [xs[y] for ys in bins.values() for y in ys]

    return out

_check_n = 0
def check(n, xs):
    ys = list(foo(xs, n))

    try:
        for y in ys:
            assert len(y) <= n
        print(".", end="")
        n+=1
        if n % 10 == 0:
            sys.stdout.flush()
    except:
        print("n, xs =", (n, xs))
        print("ys =", ys)
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n, xs = 12, [ ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"], ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8"], ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6"], ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"] ]
    check(n, xs)

    cases = 10**4
    max_n = 10**2
    max_input_len = 10**3

    for i in range(cases):
        n = random.randint(1, max_n)
        xs = [[1] * random.randint(1, n) for j in range(random.randint(1, max_input_len))]
        check(n, xs)
```